# How to input multiple departure dates and times in gmapsdistance R package?

Tags: r, google-distancematrix-api

I am using the R package, gmapsdistance, to extract Google distance matrix.

My codes are:

```
gdm <- gmapsdistance(origin = origin_vector,
                     destination = destination_vector,
                     combinations = "pairwise", 
                     mode = "driving",
                     shape = "long",
                     dep_date = date_vector, 
                     dep_time = time_vector)
```

The Google API key was also set. The code works until the parameters for dep_date and dep_time. I believe it is because the parameters do not accept vectors. Two errors appear:
1: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document.
2: Extra content at the end of the document.

In my dataset, each row is a data point with a unique origin, destination, departure date, and departure time. I require the Google distance/time for each row and there are thousands of them. There is no need for me to compare across rows. How may I do this?

Appreciate any help!